# python dictionaries - combine values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have these dictionaries

```
{
    'id': 5,
    'quantity: 10
}

{
    'id': 5,
    'quantity: 15
}
```

I want something like this

```
{
    'id': 5,
    'quantity': 25
}
```

EDIT: Basically, I want to combine the quantity of similar `ids`
Sorry if I simplified my question way too much. Yes I have a list of these dicts

```
products = [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]
```

Comment: Are those different dictionaries in a list or something?. Please state your question clearly and with examples

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple solution that uses a for loop to to iterate over each key in dic1

```
dic1 = {'id': 5, 'quantity': 10}
dic2 = {'id': 5, 'quantity': 15}

for key in dic1:
    if key in dic2:
        dic1[key] += dic2[key]
```

Comment: Same problem as my solution below but a bit more drastic; if the dictionaries don't share the exact same keys, you will get a `KeyError`. Still agree that this is a solution to the problem presented by the OP.

Comment: That gives `{'id':10,'quantity':25}, while the OP asks for `{ 'id': 5,  'quantity': 25}`

Comment: This will add the `id`s as well.

Comment: @colopop The for-loop loops over keys in dic1 and checks whether they're in dic2. So the block in the `if` statement shouldn't be called unless `key` is in both dictionaries.

Comment: The op said "Basically, I want to combine the quantity of similar ids" im standing by our solutions to the ops problem.

Comment: @Acccumulation True enough, I misread the code. However, there is still the more subtle problem that if a key is in `dic2` but not in `dic1`, that key will not be represented in the resulting dict. It is unclear if this is incorrect or exactly what the OP wants (or irrelevant because it will never come up in their situation).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dict comprehension.

```
d = {key: dict1[key] + dict2[key] for key in dict1}
```

This will work if and only if your dictionaries have exactly the same keys. In more complex situations, you'll either have unrepresented keys or throw a `KeyError`. If this is a problem, you might try using `collections.Counter` objects (avoids `KeyError` by having default values of 0 for integers) or just refactoring your code and breaking this out into a loop to get exactly what you need.

This will work if there is a chance that the dicts will have different IDs:

```
from collections import Counter
c1 = Counter(dict1)

for key in dict2:
   c1[key] += dict2[key]
```

`c1` is your added-together dict. If `dict1` has keys that aren't in `dict2`, they will appear in `c1` from the initialization step. If `dict2` has keys that aren't in `dict1`, they will be added to `c1` without modification.

Comment: Works only if the set of the keys is exactly the same in both dictionaries.

Comment: @jo9k Noted in my edit -- you beat me to it. However, that is the situation presented by the OP; it is unclear what they want if the keys in the dicts differ.